# can boto3’s get_user_attribute_verification_code() be used as sending confirmation code to already verified users?

Tags: boto3, amazon-cognito

Just as written in title, I’m wondering that it is a good practice to use boto3’s
[get_user_attribute_verification_code() method](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cognito-idp.html?highlight=user_attribute#CognitoIdentityProvider.Client.get_user_attribute_verification_code) for **sending confirmation code even though user is already verified.**

The purpose is to activate user when the user hasn’t logged in for more than a year.
And I want to send a confirmation code by email to check if the user trying to log in is really the owner of the email address registered.

Since I’m using AWS cognito for user authentication, I thought it would be good to use what I already have.

I found that the `get_user_attribute_verification_code()` can be used to send confirmation code but
in most of examples, this method is used to verify email when signing up.

So, using `get_user_attribute_verification_code()` to user who’s already verified could cause any trouble in cognito’s user attribute?
Or are there any other methods that can be used to send confirmation code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can always deactivate such users and they will need to verify again.

Comment: @AleksanderWons Do you mean using [admin_disable_user()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cognito-idp.html#CognitoIdentityProvider.Client.admin_disable_user) method? I’ve tried this but the method blocks user from sign in step... Inactive user has to sign in first to activate their account, so I couldn’t use this method. Thank you anyway for the comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realized you cannot change the status back to `UNCONFIRMED`. But there is still way around it.

Whey you want to force a user to re-validate the email address, simply change the `email_verified` attribute to `false`. Now, set up a Pre-Authentication lambda, that would check if that field is set to false. Something like this:

```
if event['request']['userAttributes']['email_verified'] is False:
    client.get_user_attribute_verification_code()
```

This will re-send the code.

This has a potential downside - each time a user tries to log in, an email is sent. You could try to work around it by logging how often someone tries to sign in and block it temporarily (or use an exponential backoff).